# Apache httpclient / Java: Rate limits (429)

Tags: java, rate-limiting

Hopefully you can help me with the following: Some webshop APIs have a Rate limit process built in. Rate limit is an important element in keeping their IT landscape safe and reliable on the one hand, and fairly distributing the available capacity on the other.

For example, we request stock data from a JAVA process, using an http client (groupId: org.apache.httpcomponents, version 4.5.5). While executing this request, we exceed the Rate limit.Each response message contains information about rate limits, such as how much request budget you have left, when the budget will be replenished, and so on.

Question: do you also run into this, and how can you solve this by means of apache httpcomponents? Side node: authentication token is only valid for 5 minutes, how can you refresh it before retrying the call after receiving a 429 response code.

I would like to hear from you

Comment: I do not think you will get an answer inside of HTTPClient, because what you want to do on rate limits depends on the application... Abandon all ? Retry later ? Not even try if you know you'll hit a limit ? Preemptively schedule requests before even reaching the limit, keeping a safety margin ? It all actually is **application specific**, and not at all **http related**. It's an integration issue. I *think* your best bet would be to design an async component around your API call, with messaging policies for implementing throughput control. There may be libs that already package this.